# Django context does not render in base template

Tags: django

I appreciate that similar questions have been asked before, but after looking at them, I still cannot seem to solve my issue.

By following the documentation, I have the below files:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.

def base(request):
    articles = 'articles'
    dboard = 'dashboard'
    pages = {'dboard':dboard, 'Articles':articles}
    return render(request, 'collatedata/base.html', pages)


def dash(request):
    return render(request, 'collatedata/dash.html')
```

collatedata/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dash, name='dash'),
]
```

main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('collatedata.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

base.html:

```
...

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white p-3 mb-2">
                  <i class="fas fa-home text-light fa-lg mr-3"></i>
                  {{ dboard }}
                </a>
              </li>

...
```

dash.html

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}
```

however, the output does not read {{ dboard }}

so returns this:

```
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white p-3 mb-2">
                  <i class="fas fa-home text-light fa-lg mr-3"></i>

                </a>
              </li>
```

could it be to do with base.html being extended?

Comment: Views do not inherit or wrap each other magically when a related template extends or includes any other template. So `base` view is not executed each time when `dash` is. So you have to pass the context in the `dash` view in a similar way as you do in `base` view.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thanks

Comment: and what about urls.py ?

Comment: i've added sections from both urls.py files. the issue, however, is as Ivan stated. If you know a more efficient way to pass python objects into multiple html files that rely onthe same template, that would be very helpful.